# A custom string implementation to overload operators << and >> for a binary shift of string characters in c#

Tags: c#, string, overloading, operator-keyword

I would like to know how to implement a MyString class in c# and overloading operators `<<` and `>>`.
For example :

```
MyString name = "string";

Console.Write(name<<3) // It will print **ingstr** by shifting last 3 to left
```

My current implementation is as below:

```
public sealed class MyString
{
    private readonly string _value="";

    public MyString(string str)
    {
        _value = str;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _value;
    }

    public static implicit operator MyString(string str)
    {
        var myString = new MyString(str);
        return myString;
    }

    public static explicit operator string(MyString myString)
    {
        return myString._value;
    }

    public override bool Equals(Object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var s = obj as MyString;
        if ((object)s == null)
            return false;

        return _value.Equals(obj);
    }

    public bool Equals(MyString str)
    {
        return _value.Equals(str);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return _value.GetHashCode();
    }

    public static bool operator ==(MyString a, MyString b)
    {
        return a._value.Equals(b.ToString());
    }

    public static bool operator !=(MyString a, MyString b)
    {
        return !(a == b);
    }

    public static MyString operator <<(MyString s, int shift)
    {
        if (shift <= 0)
        {
            return s;
        }

        shift = shift % s._value.Length;
        return s._value.Substring(shift, s._value.Length - shift)
             + s._value.Substring(0, shift);
    }

    public static MyString operator >>(MyString s, int shift)
    {
        if (shift <= 0)
            return s;
        shift = shift%s._value.Length;

        return s._value.Substring(shift, s._value.Length - shift) +             s._value.Substring(0,shift);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Firstly, I'd discourage you from doing this to start with - but have you tried it? How far have you got? What problems have you run into?

Comment: Don't put it in comments - edit your *question*. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: So you've now shown your implementation so far - what's gone wrong when trying to implement the shift operator? You clearly know how to overload operators as you're doing it for `==` and `!=` (although it's a bit odd that you haven't overridden Equals and GetHashCode) so what went wrong with `<<`?

Comment: @JonSkeet I dont know how to implement the logic for << and >>, there is no issues with == and != as they are working fine

Comment: Please consider marking the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

If I really needed it, I would write something along the lines of:

```
public static string operator << (MyString s, int shift)
{
    if(shift <= 0)
    {
        return s;
    }

    shift = shift % s.Length;
    return s.String.Substring(shift, s.Length - shift)
         + s.String.Substring(0, shift);
}
```

Though, it is not clear why you want to implement the shift as an operator of your own class. How about just defining an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) on the String itself? Then you would be able to do something like:

```
string str = "name".ShiftLeft(2);
```

Comment: I suggest doing shift % s.Length instead of throwing IAE.

Comment: Would also check for zero, to return original string.

Comment: first you should %, and only then check for zero. If negative, call the >> with positive shift.

Comment: I updated the code as above and when testing for << operator my test failed as below:
  Expected: "anNaum"
  But was:  <umanNa>

Comment: @MikeHermann why did you expect "anNaum"? If the initial text was "Nauman" and we shift two characters to the **left**, I would expect "umanNa".

Comment: I did some changes to code by @Shedal and it worked fine. The same code didn't work as it is but still was a great start point. Thank you guys for help. :)